# Tkinter color-chooser window focus

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have three windows:

- Root window
- Toplevel window
- Color-chooser window.

The root window has a menu command that opens the toplevel. The toplevel has a button that opens the color-chooser.

When the color-chooser button is pressed and the color-chooser opens, something weird happens. The toplevel window gets sent BEHIND the root window.

The layering of the windows is like this before clicking the button:

- ROOT
- TOPLEVEL

The layering of the windows is like this after clicking the button:

- TOPLEVEL
- ROOT
- COLORCHOOSER

Why is this happening? How can I stop this from happening? (I'm using Windows 7, and python 2.7)

Here is a simplified working code example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkColorChooser

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.menu = Menu(self)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Open Toplevel", command=self.create_toplevel)
        self.config(menu=self.menu)

    def create_toplevel(self):
        self.new_toplevel = TopLevelWithButton(self)

class TopLevelWithButton(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Color Chooser", command=self.open_chooser)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def open_chooser(self):
        tkColorChooser.askcolor()

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't telling the color dialog which window it belongs to, so by default it attaches itself to the root window. With some window managers this will cause the parent window to be raised to the top of the stacking order.

Try passing in the `parent` attribute, giving it a value of the toplevel window:

```
tkChooseColor.askcolor(parent=self)
```